# sentence case json property is not mapping with pojo class in rest api

Tags: java

i am making a post request to rest api from postman with body as json :

```
{
 "username":"ramakanta",
 "password":"test",
 "StudentID":"1025"
}
```

And server side resouces are

```
public class PushDataEntity {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String StudentID;    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getStudentID() {
        return StudentID;
    }
    @JsonProperty("StudentID")
    public void setStudentID(String StudentID) {
        this.StudentID = StudentID;
    }
}

@Path("/pushdata")

public class PushDataServiceImpl {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response       dataPush(@Context HttpServletRequest request,PushDataEntity pushDataEntity) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(pushDataEntity.getStudentID());//null
  }
```

username and password is mapping but StudentID is not mapping to pojo property. I have tried adding @JsonProperty("StudentID") to setter , getter and property level even , didn't workout. i dont want any change in json, what i should change in java side to make that json property mapped to pojo property. please provide a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not following Java conventions? Fields should be declared using lower camel case

Answer (score 3):

You are sending `StudentId`, but having `StudentID` in POJO (the last "d" is different). Either change the JSON in request, or add `@JsonProperty("StudentId")` annotation to the POJO.

**UPDATE**

Signature of the method is wrong, there is no such annotation: `@ContextHttpServletRequestrequest`, it should be

```
public Response dataPush(@Context HttpServletRequest request,,PushDataEntity pushDataEntity) throws Exception {
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake, i am sending {"StudentID":"1025"} in json.

Comment: i updated my question. Is it because of pojo property  in sentence case ,so  i am getting null every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `@JsonProperty` over the getter function of `StudentID`.